# counting instances between two tags

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file with multiple tags and I want to count the years between certain tags like this

```
    <Dateline>08/Dec./2009</Dateline>
```

I simply want to get how many 2009s and 2010s and so on the day and the month are not important, I want it like this

- 2008 >>  10
- 2009 >>  11
- 2010 >>  12
- 2011 >>  15
- 2012 >>  20

  Tried working it in perl but no luck.
  Also is it possible to print whats between these tags, no matter what date or words in a outside file.

Sample XML:

```
<Sabanews> 
    <ID>SBN_ARB_0000001</ID> 
    <Start URL>sabanews.net/ar/news200024.htm</Start URL> 
    <Headline>الكونجرس الأمريكي يطالب المجتمع الدولي دعم اليمن لمواجهة التحديات القائمة</Headline> 
    <Dateline>08/ديسمبر/2009</Dateline> 
    <Text> واشنطن ـ سبأنت: طالب الكون المزعزعة للاستقرار والعو اليمنيين خصوصا أن يعملوا معا لمجابهة التحديات القائمة". سبأ</Text> 
</Sabanews>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? For XML parsing, I'd normally suggest use `XML::Twig`.

Comment: Use an XML parser. Can you show us that "tried working it in perl" part?

Comment: Also - could you give a bit more of your XML sample for context? I assume there's more than one element?

Comment: By 'whats between these tags' what do you mean? Simply printing the text "08/Dec./2009"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplification, because your specification is vague. Firm it up a bit, and I may clarify/extend. As is, treat as an example of an approach that could be taken.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
my %count_of;

sub extract_date {
    my ( $twig, $dateline ) = @_;
    my $date_string = $dateline->text;
    print $date_string,"\n";
    my ($year) = ( $date_string =~ m#/(\d+)$# );
    $count_of{$year}++;
}

my $parser = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'Dateline' => \&extract_date } );
#probably want parsefile here in your real world code.
$parser->parse( \*DATA );


foreach my $date ( sort keys %count_of ) {
    print $date, " >> ", $count_of{$date}, "\n";
}


__DATA__
<XML>
<Dateline>01/Dec./2009</Dateline>
<Dateline>02/Dec./2009</Dateline>
<Dateline>03/Dec./2020</Dateline>
<Dateline>04/Dec./2015</Dateline>
<Dateline>05/Dec./2015</Dateline>
</XML>
```

We set a handler, that's triggered each time we see a 'Dateline' element, and ignore anything else.

This handler extracts the text from the element, uses a regular expression to extract the year, and then adds it to `%count_of`. Which we print afterwards.

Gives:

```
01/Dec./2009
02/Dec./2009
03/Dec./2020
04/Dec./2015
05/Dec./2015
2009 >> 2
2015 >> 2
2020 >> 1
```

Edit: Given the new sample XML - you need something slightly different to the above. The approach should still work though.

Google translate tells me that `ديسمبر` is "December" so it' still a date. You may find that using `Time::Piece` parses it correctly as that should support locale.

Otherwise you need to extract your 'year' with:

```
my ($year) = ( $date_string =~ m#^\d+/(\d+)/\w+$# );
```

Edit: To handle 'command line' specification of filename:

```
my ( $filename ) = @ARGV;

$parser -> parsefile ( $filename );
```

This'll let you run `xmlparse.pl <filename>`.

Comment: Thank you @Sobrique, Here is a sample of the XML didn't want to put t  it all because it is in Arabic '<Sabanews>
 <ID>SBN_ARB_0000001</ID>
 <Start URL>http://www.sabanews.net/ar/news200024.htm</Start URL>
 <Headline>الكونجرس الأمريكي يطالب المجتمع الدولي دعم اليمن لمواجهة التحديات القائمة</Headline>
 <Dateline>08/ديسمبر/2009</Dateline>
 <Text> واشنطن ـ سبأنت: طالب الكون المزعزعة للاستقرار والعو اليمنيين خصوصا أن يعملوا معا لمجابهة التحديات القائمة". سبأ</Text>
</Sabanews>'

Comment: Ah, you see, that doesn't match the sample you originally gave - the `<Dateline>` element includes extra text.

Comment: @Borodin - good solution to the problem. I've just posted to `meta` about it :)

Comment: @IbrahimHassan: Arabic is fine, as long as we don't need to understand it. Even then we should usually be okay -- most of us are professional programmers. What we *do* need to know is what the real data looks like

Comment: Textpad is thorougly confused by it though, so one or other RE might work. Hopefully it illustrates the problem though.

Comment: Here is how I run the script from CMD line 

perl xmlcounter.pl news.xml>yearcount

I'm getting an error in this line 

$parser->parse( \*Data ); 

Should I put my file name or what

Comment: TextPad is famously confused by all things Unicode. [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) gets it right

Comment: Yes, that `*DATA` line is reading the data inline from the file. If you're piping XML to it, then you'll need to `*STDIN` instead.

Comment: like this:

$parser->parse (*STDIN);

Comment: Or otherwise - if you're reading files from `ARGV` you want `parsefile` instead. E.g. `my ( $filename ) = @ARGV;` and `$parser -> parsefile ( $filename );`

Comment: `$parser -> parse ( *STDIN );` would apply if you wanted to `cat news.xml | xmlcounter.pl`.

Comment: That was the final code as you said, but I'm getting this error:

not well-formed (invalid token) at line 4, column 11, byte 63 at C:/Perl64/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187. at xmlcounter.pl line 20.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my %count_of;

sub extract_date {
    my ( $twig, $dateline ) = @_;
    my $date_string = $dateline->text;
    print $date_string,"\n";
 my ($year) = ( $date_string =~ m#^\d+/(\d+)/\w+$# );    
 $count_of{$year}++;
}

my $parser = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'Dateline' => \&extract_date } );
my ($filename) = @ARGV;

$parser -> parsefile ( $filename ); 

foreach my $date ( sort keys %count_of ) {
    print $date, " >> ", $count_of{$date}, "\n";
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73957/discussion-between-ibrahim-hassan-and-sobrique).